# Generated .ics file from Outlook has wrong UNTIL property for recurrent events

Tags: c#, icalendar

I have a calendar in Outlook and I am exporting it as .ics file. The calendar has recurrent events (events that repeat). For multiple events I have the same issue.

I have a weekly recurring event. Outlook says: Occurs every Sunday effective 6/10/2018 until 3/28/2019

However when I export the calendar into a .ics file, the event looks like this:

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
DESCRIPTION:\n
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20180923T000000Z;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=SU;WKST=MO
UID:040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E0080000000060CACBCE03C6D301000000000000000
 0100000002A073D46A060504CAAA06CE73B51C945
SUMMARY:my weekly
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20180610
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20180611
CLASS:PUBLIC
PRIORITY:5
DTSTAMP:20180327T194506Z
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SEQUENCE:0
LOCATION:
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-APPT-SEQUENCE:0
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:FREE
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-INTENDEDSTATUS:BUSY
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-ALLDAYEVENT:TRUE
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-INSTTYPE:1
X-MICROSOFT-DONOTFORWARDMEETING:FALSE
X-MICROSOFT-DISALLOW-COUNTER:FALSE
END:VEVENT
```

You can see that the Untill property, instead of showing the correct date which is 3/28/2019, it is set to 20180923T000000Z. It's not even close.

So naturally when I import the events in code via the file, I get wrong value. This issue also happens for other evens that repeat after a lot of time, for examplea yearly occurence that only happens twice, starting from this year.

If I create the same event in Google Calendar, the until property is UNTIL=20190328;

Answer (score 0):

Neither are wrong. Please see the RFC 5545 specification. One is using the ‘ datetime’ format  with the UTC time one
And the other is using the ‘date’ format. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.3.4

It’s a little hard to get clarity on the UNTIL part, but the way I read it both are acceptable. The examples all use the DATETIME in UTC Timezone.
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.5.2

Comment: The UNTILL value should be 2019032018, but instead it is 20180923T000000Z. It is off by a year. I think timezone isn't the issue here. Or am I missing something?

Comment: My bad, I thought you were talking about the formats. IF Outlook has such an obvious bug surely it would have been noticed before, yet a quick google only shows this post. So that suggests either a time delay in the ics file being updated ? maybe if you first had the 2018 date? or user error?  I don't use outlook so can't test myself.  Are you consistently able to repeat the problem - ie with clean new event does it still happen?

Comment: Yes it does consistently happen, as you can see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49528728/exported-ics-file-from-outlook-has-incorrect-values-off-by-a-year

Comment: Ah ok, then I think the most appropriate place to raise that would be the microsoft outlook forums, not here, as it sounds like a bug in outlook, not an icalendar programming question per se.

Comment: It turns out this was the issue: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_other-mso_o365b/how-to-get-published-office365-calendar-to-have/45d8c2f7-9aa0-4321-8839-3e4abf3698bb

Microsoft has a range for visible events on publish.